# Help with a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

Given the following tables I would like to know how to write a query to return only the categories that have books in them and the number of books for each category. A book can be added in one or many categories. I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Here are my tables:

**categories table**
- id
- name
- permalink

**books table**
- id
- title
- author
- description
- price

**books_categories table**
- id
- book_id
- category_id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select c.id
      ,c.name
      ,count(*) as num_books
  from categories c
  join books_categories bc on(bc.category_id = c.id)
 group 
    by c.id
      ,c.name;
```

Use `LEFT JOIN` if you also want the categories without books.

Comment: I think using caps for the SQL parts makes queries considerably better to read. I allowed myself to edit it.

Comment: Uppercase keywords became useless and wasteful the second we got color screens and syntax high-lightning. I rolledback to my own personal taste.

Comment: I won't start a rollback war but I disagree with you. Quite often in the PHP world queries are placed between quotes and that will disable the coloring advantage.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM books_categories AS bc
LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = bc.category_id
GROUP BY c.id
```

You'll get a `count` column with the number of rows for each category. Categories with zero books (that is those with no entry in table books_categories) won't be returned.

Comment: I think you put the tables in the wrong order (or you meant right join).

Comment: @Ronnis, I don't think so. I use queries like this and they work fine. As long as I want to get only the categories with some books assigned, this works ok.

Comment: Your query does not match your description of it. Categories with zero books will not be included in your result. To fix this, you either need to use RIGHT JOIN (if mysql supports it) or change the order of the tables. In fact, unless there are missing RI constraints and garbage data, your query is identical to an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT categories.id, 
    COUNT(books_categories.id) AS number
FROM categories
    LEFT JOIN books_categories ON books_categories.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY categories.id
HAVING number > 0;
```